# Question about how to evaluate healthcare professional - On-topic?

Tags: discussion

I needed to find a new dentist as my previous dentist sold his practice to go work for the VA (he's an ex-Marine).  I chose one based on very positive reviews on several sites such as healthgrades.com but my initial experience was extremely negative due to high-pressure sales tactics for unrequested cosmetic procedures.

I want to ask about the process of evaluating a healthcare professional, hopefully prior to making the first appointment.

Is this on topic here?

Comment: I would say so. I don't think you can expect much of abtrudelt though. Best thing is: If you doubt your doctor, change him/her.

Comment: Actually, an excellent question might be whether there is evidence that online rating sites are accurate predictors of actual physician performance.  There is some scattered data out there on accuracy of patient questionnaires within healthcare systems, but not sure about the healthcare providers!

Comment: A way to phrase your actual question might be "what methods are available for a prospective patient to learn as much as they can about a doctor when choosing which provider to see?"  Both questions are related.